# How does python create class using attributes in the parameter list of __new__() function?

Tags: python, metaclass

I want to know how the `__new__` function of type works, how can it create a class using the attr parameters.

for Example:

```
class ModelMetaclass(type): 
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class User(Model): 
    __metaclass__ = ModelMetaclass
    id = StringField(primary_key=True, ddl='varchar(50)')
    email = StringField(ddl='varchar(50)')
    password = StringField(ddl='varchar(50)')

class StringField(Field):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.name = kw.get('name', None)
        self.primary_key = kw.get('primary_key', False)
        self.ddl= kw.get('ddl', '')
```

Then, you can use User class like this:
    u = User(id=10190, name='Michael', email='orm@db.org')
    print type(u.id)

So, how does the `__new__` function translate StringField into str ?

Answer (score 0):

> how does the `__new__` function translate `StringField` into `str` ?

Short answer: it doesn't - at least not in the code snippet you posted. Also, the `StringField`s are *class* attributes, not instance attributes, so `self.id` is not necessarily `User.id`.

Now you didn't post all the relevant code (we'd need to see at least the full `ModelMetaclass`, the `Model` class and the `Field` class code) nor any mention of where this code comes from, so it's hard to tell exactly what happens here. I assume there's much to  than what you posted here, and FWIW `Field` could be a descriptor, or the whole thing could work like Django's `Model` and `ModelField` (where the `ModelField` are used for the ORM part but the matching `Model` instance attributes are just plain instance attributes).